# SCons: How to put multiple output files in cache

Tags: caching, scons

Our compiler produces a debug file in addition to the object file. This debug file is needed for the final debugging target. I already added this file as additional dependency for the target. But when using a CacheDir() this file should be stored together with the object file.

I already tried to add the debug file as a SideEffect() and Depends() of the object file as well as Depends() of the final target. But I had no luck with this. SCons only stores the object file in the CacheDir() and does not know how to build the debug file.

Is it possible to store both files in the cache directory, so that they are both retrieved when building the target?

Answer (score 1):

To get two build variants in the same run you have to use different names for generated files. In case of C/C++ project this can be achieved through *OBJSUFFIX* environment variable. The code below will make all debug output object files appear with '.dbg.o' suffix instead of '.o'.

```
dbg_env = env.Clone(...)
dbg_env.Append(...) # add debug flags
dbg_env.Prepend(OBJSUFFIX = '.dbg')
```